# How to addTenant to TenantScope with Confide/Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I am using

- Laravel
- Confide (for users authentication
- Laravel Multi Tenant (for multi-tenant administration)

I try to include the Laravel Mutli Tenant package so that each user can only see their own data (own clients, own leads, etc).

It seems [(documentation)](https://github.com/AuraEQ/laravel-multi-tenant) I should use this command to add a tenant

```
TenantScope::addTenant($tenantColumn, $tenantId)
```

I don't know where I should add this line of code. Here is what I tried:

**1. Add to my route file**

```
TenantScope::addTenant('user_id', 1);
```

Works but I know it's not the right way to do so.

**2. Add to the UsersController.php**

I added

```
TenantScope::addTenant('user_id', 1);
```

But I get an error:

```
AuraIsHere\LaravelMultiTenant\TenantScope: tenant column "user_id" NOT found in tenants scope "[]"
```

How should I proceed to get the actual user_id when a user logins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference: The solution was simple! I will use a route filter:

```
Route::filter('multitenant', function(){
    TenantScope::addTenant('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
});
```

and use this filter

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth|multitenant'), function(){...
```